# How do I install .NET Core on OSX?

Tags: macos, install, microsoft

What commands are needed to install .NET Core on OSX?

Answer (score 4):

These instructions come [from the Microsoft site.](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos)

1. Install HomeBrew:

<sub>(Paste into Terminal.)</sub>

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. Update homebrew:

   ```
   brew update
   ```
3. Install OpenSSL:

[Source](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos)

```
brew install openssl
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

4. Finally install .NET core, [download here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/C/F/DCFA73BE-93CE-4DA0-AB76-98972FD6E475/dotnet-sdk-2.1.101-osx-gs-x64.pkg):

   [image]

Comment: open ssl is not .Net core

Comment: @Mark - It is a requirement of the .NET core install. Please see the link in step 2. Are you saying that MSFT is incorrect on their site?

Comment: Yes but your scripts one;y install openssl and not .Net 9and surely any package manage manages dependences)

Comment: These aren't "my" scripts.  These come from the MSFT website linked above

Comment: The step 3 is not obvious in your answer  please provide more than the link to make it equal to the other parts

Comment: I added a screenshot, emphasized the download link, and made sure to capture the screen that says OpenSSL is required. @mark

Comment: I made an edit to separate the steps of updating homebrew and downloading OpenSSL. I also updated the download URL for .NET Core since it was 1.5 years old. The URL I changed it to seems to still be tied to a specific version, so it will be outdated eventually too. If someone can find a URL that always points to the newest version that would be better.